# Remove First and Last Paragraph, Also Retain Last Paragraph Separately

Tags: php, arrays, substring

I am printing out some data from an array for a project, but I would like to remove the first and last paragraphs. But retain the last paragraph for attribution separately to output on it's own.

I would like the remove the first paragraph beginning `From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia.` and the final paragraph, beginning `Description above from the Wikipedia article Humphrey Bogart, licensed under CC-BY-SA, full list of contributors on Wikipedia.`

To call the row, I am just using a simple PHP echo statement: `$actor_biography = $actor_details['biography'];`, before echoing out `$actor_biography`

**Code:**

```
Array
(
    [adult] => 
    [also_known_as] => Array
        (
        )

    [biography] => From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia.  

Humphrey DeForest Bogart (December 25, 1899 – January 14, 1957) was an American actor. He is widely regarded as a cultural icon. The American Film Institute ranked Bogart as the greatest male star in the history of American cinema.

After trying various jobs, Bogart began acting in 1921 and became a regular in Broadway productions in the 1920s and 1930s. When the stock market crash of 1929 reduced the demand for plays, Bogart turned to film. His first great success was as Duke Mantee in The Petrified Forest (1936), and this led to a period of typecasting as a gangster with films such as Angels with Dirty Faces (1938) and B-movies like The Return of Doctor X (1939).

His breakthrough as a leading man came in 1941, with High Sierra and The Maltese Falcon. The next year, his performance in Casablanca raised him to the peak of his profession and, at the same time, cemented his trademark film persona, that of the hard-boiled cynic who ultimately shows his noble side. Other successes followed, including To Have and Have Not (1944), The Big Sleep (1946), Dark Passage (1947) and Key Largo (1948), with his wife Lauren Bacall; The Treasure of the Sierra Madre (1948); The African Queen (1951), for which he won his only Academy Award; Sabrina (1954) and The Caine Mutiny (1954). His last movie was The Harder They Fall (1956). During a film career of almost thirty years, he appeared in 75 feature films.

Description above from the Wikipedia article Humphrey Bogart, licensed under CC-BY-SA, full list of contributors on Wikipedia.
    [birthday] => 1899-12-25
    [deathday] => 1957-01-14
    [homepage] => 
    [id] => 4110
    [imdb_id] => nm0000007
    [name] => Humphrey Bogart
    [place_of_birth] => New York City, New York, USA
    [popularity] => 3.92
    [profile_path] => /5WaI2QbYd6WYq7Mzk3tEUTXSM3u.jpg
)
```

Comment: That would probably be a violation of the Wikipedia terms of use. Not only are you scraping their site (which they don't really love either), but you also intend to remove the attribution?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this - I'm not too happy about it, either, to be honest, but my tutor would like me to remove the lines, so it's something I have to do. As for scraping the site, I'm actually just using TMDb's API, which scrapes Wikipedia for an actor's details, so it's not me who's doing the scraping - I'm just printing out data from TMDb.

Comment: Actually, if it were possible to somehow extract the final paragraph into a separate row for me to print out separately, I can display it a little nicer, which would probably appease my tutor and allow me to keep the attribution.

Comment: Well, a paragraph seems to be defined by "\n\n" in your text. So you just need to split your text in an array...

Comment: Madara Uchiha gave you a more concrete example for that. Now you need to remove the first and last elements of the array. Madara Uchiha will also provide the code for that.

Comment: @AlexRyans I have a working example and demo below, check it out and see if it works out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$para = 'Pellentesque quis sodales nunc. Integer mi lacus, hendrerit posuere adipiscing sed, sagittis non lectus. Fusce eleifend felis enim. Curabitur sagittis libero neque. Proin a tortor eros, interdum interdum metus. Pellentesque non quam non sem commodo facilisis. Duis fermentum sollicitudin gravida. Sed eros lorem, rutrum ac viverra nec, tempor id nulla. Integer congue malesuada massa? Sed porttitor varius felis, sit amet pharetra metus consequat fringilla? In non leo metus, eget tristique arcu? In magna mauris, mollis blandit posuere id; pulvinar vel libero. Ut vel augue vel leo semper interdum lobortis a magna. Nunc ac elit ipsum; vitae mollis eros. Phasellus erat sem, elementum semper vehicula eu, cursus et neque. Ut ac lorem felis.

Maecenas vel urna felis. Maecenas sed ante libero, sit amet consectetur neque. Duis eget eros ligula, non varius neque. Etiam sit amet interdum mi. Praesent ac sapien gravida ante congue suscipit! Pellentesque feugiat velit sed enim semper vitae gravida lorem mattis. Donec dapibus odio vitae velit laoreet laoreet!

Nam et turpis magna. Aliquam ultrices leo in lectus venenatis id facilisis nisl iaculis. Fusce euismod, ipsum dignissim pharetra iaculis, turpis lectus iaculis magna, vel adipiscing arcu arcu in nibh. Sed ullamcorper faucibus massa vel tincidunt. Nunc condimentum ornare mi, ut tempus erat vehicula tempor. Sed pulvinar nulla at tortor lacinia auctor. Proin eget enim diam, in adipiscing diam. Praesent neque arcu, pellentesque vel gravida nec, elementum et ante? Quisque blandit, nulla id semper pellentesque, eros dolor laoreet dui, sit amet placerat libero libero non ligula. Praesent commodo dictum viverra. Proin egestas diam a nunc dapibus eu sollicitudin turpis semper? Etiam at tincidunt magna. Phasellus ullamcorper eros sit amet massa convallis ut molestie orci vestibulum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nam fringilla, ante vel facilisis venenatis, sapien leo accumsan mi, id ultrices nibh lectus id orci. Donec dignissim sapien a risus tempor hendrerit.

Proin egestas libero id diam dapibus non accumsan lacus cursus. Cras vel lectus ut ligula condimentum interdum eget fringilla magna. Suspendisse pulvinar sem lacus, at facilisis lectus. Vestibulum elit sapien, semper vel commodo nec; ultrices nec lorem. Quisque erat dui, faucibus at convallis nec, aliquam in nulla. Donec vulputate libero in sapien dictum vel feugiat turpis bibendum! Duis nec mauris libero, a hendrerit risus. Integer tempus, magna in aliquet volutpat, sapien dui sagittis ante, ut convallis sem purus at diam. Proin auctor, nisi sed sagittis vulputate, leo arcu commodo lorem; vel convallis quam quam ut nisl! Curabitur hendrerit dolor id mi hendrerit eget lobortis nibh sollicitudin. Vestibulum aliquet; libero eleifend placerat posuere, lorem est molestie nunc, id pellentesque nisi massa nec ligula.

Praesent urna nisi, rhoncus scelerisque cursus vitae, condimentum quis augue. Duis ac lacus eget eros dignissim auctor. Duis at nunc eros! Nulla rutrum ullamcorper nisi, ac fermentum dui varius quis. Cras condimentum leo adipiscing augue tempor at lacinia elit suscipit. Pellentesque dui est, feugiat sed accumsan ac, aliquam id risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean nec felis quis velit faucibus aliquam eget ac tellus. Praesent congue velit ut metus placerat sed ultrices enim egestas.';

$start_sec = strpos($para, "\n");  // get start position of 2nd paragraph
$start_end = strrpos($para, "\n"); // get start position of last paragraph

$new_para = trim(substr($para, $start_sec, $start_end - $start_sec)); // get substring of content until start of last paragraph
$last_para = trim(substr($para, $start_end)); // get substring of content from start of last paragraph until end

echo $new_para;  // output all paragraphs but first and last
echo $last_para; // output last paragraph
```

If you need more explanation I can explain some more, but it's pretty straightforward. It will output content without first and last paragraphs and also allow you to output the last paragraph separately.

See : **[DEMO](http://codepad.org/DC8a25AN)**

Comment: Thank you! This has worked perfectly. Really appreciate the help, and I can finally keep the attribution.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see from the image you provided (please provide actual code next time!), the string is separated by double line-breaks. In which case, you could do:

```
$result_array = explode("\n\n", $string);
```

Which would give you an array with each paragraph.

Consider leaving the attributions intact. Use the `<small>` and `<footer>` HTML tags to designate it as such.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment! I'm definitely going to try to leave the attributions intact as much as I can. As requested, I've added the original array code.

Comment: I have updated my original post with new information, based on your suggestion.